# Antlr 4 : manually creating trees

Tags: antlr4

I have long been "kicking the tires" on porting my existing query language parser from Antlr 2 to Antlr 4.  But as Antlr 4 represents a major deviation from Antlr 2 and Antlr 3 this represents a significant risk as I do not fully know Antlr 4; I am know Antlr 2, and Antlr 3 is close enough to it that I am at least comfortable there.  The existing translation (to SQL ultimately) relies on 2 major tenants that are no longer available in Antlr 4: tree walking (tree parsers) and tree re-writing.  Basically I had a multi-phase translation where each phase output a slightly more normalized/simplified tree.  To an extent I feel some of that is still needed.  Perhaps it is simply my unfamiliarity with Antlr 4.  But in either case, I simply do not see how I can reasonably to this transformation walking the same original parse tree structure.

So my question is... How can I manually build an Antlr 4 tree?  The thought process here is that I would walk the first tree created from Antlr based on my initial grammar and produce a tree that matched what is expected in a second grammar I write just for producing listeners/visitors.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/antlr-discussion/vBkwCovqHcI

Comment: First just to point out that my first and only encounter with antlr was with version 4. Tree walking can be done, of course. Honestly I can't see any scenario where one would manually need to build an Antlr tree. I mean you could build some kind of your own tree or tree-like structure, but you would hardly need an Antlr tree. So my question is, do you need a tree-like structure or exactly Antlr tree? If latter, please elaborate why

Comment: Like I mentioned in the Antlr discussion group, the reason is that I would like to have Antlr generate a second listener/visitor set from a second grammar that describes the tree I am building here.